# draw a red ball on canvas using constructor function in easeljs

Tags: canvas, easeljs

here i am trying to create a red ball which is an instance of simpleBall constructor.but the code i've written is not drawing anything on the canvas.i am not sure what is wrong in my code.please help me out!!!

[fiddle for my code](http://jsfiddle.net/humptydumpty45/F34Pg/)

Code:

```
<html>
  <head>

     <script src="http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.7.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <canvas id="mycanvas" width="1000" height="500" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>

<script>
   function makeit(){

      function simpleBall(color,radius){
        this.color=color;
        this.radius=radius;
        this.initialize();

        }

  simpleBall.prototype.initialize=function(){
         this.s=this.getGraphics();
        }

  simpleBall.prototype.getGraphics=function(){
          var s=new createjs.Shape();

          s.graphics.beginFill(this.color).drawCircle(0,0,this.radius);
          return s;

        }

   var canvas=document.getElementById("mycanvas");
   var stage=new createjs.Stage(canvas);
   var ball=new simpleBall("red",10);
   ball.x=100;
   ball.y=100;
   stage.addChild(ball);
   stage.update();
   }
window.onload=makeit;
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpleBall instance "ball" is not a DisplayObject. You have to reference the `s` property instead, as that is the Shape instance. In your sample, you should be seeing an error in the console.

```
var ball=new simpleBall("red",10);
var shape = ball.s;
shape.x=100;
shape.y=100;
stage.addChild(shape);
```